# Local path planning and obstacle avoidance using local vision

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, robotics, vision

What's the best algorithm for local path planing or navigation among obstacles, using local vision system?

I have a robot in 3D environment which uses 8 camera to see environment.

The cameras gives me the physical distance between the camera and any arbitrary pixel in its images.

Also I can calculate the coordination of any arbitrary point based on its image.

I use specific colors for any thing in the environment, so I can detect obstacles based on their colors.

There is an algorithm which called VisBug to do this, but I don't like to use it. It's not efficient.

Is there any proper choice?
Thanks.

Comment: People usually use field algorithms but for planar robot is the A* the simplest and robust/efficient enough, you just need to map your surroundings (continuosly) to a planar map where each cell represents 3D box which is either empty or not ... you need just add some tweak to be sure your robot is small enough to go through space in map if your cells are smaller then him.

Comment: Field algorithms like potential field? Potential field has some problems like local minimum. 
About A*, it needs discretization, but I use continues environment. Also A* is not suitable for local planing. Fitness function needs global information.

Comment: A* can be used for local planing you do not need to map entire world use just local area from your position to desired local destination. yes field functions have their problems (therefore I do not use it if I do not have to) but most robot planner implementations I sow use it (both military and explosive disposal rescue robots)

Comment: Thanks again,
By desired local destination, you mean intermediate targets?
In A*, how you generate next node in tree in continues environment?
I've used A* in discrete path planing a lot of times. In such environment next node is moving up, down, left and right.